# Identify cross partition query in CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

How do I check if a query is a cross partition query from the Azure Diagnostic Logs? I have enabled the full-text logging but I don't see a flag in any of the tables displaying it as a Cross partition query

I am referring to this way of enabling the diagnostic logging in cosmos DB

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/diagnostic-queries-mongodb?tabs=resource-specific

Thanks
Guru

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such feature available in Azure Diagnostic Logs which can identify cross partition query in CosmosDB.